# Where will the ball land?

Tags: code-golf, simulation

Given a string where the first line contains spaces and one period (`.`, the "ball"), followed by lines containing spaces, forward slashes (`/`), and backslashes (`\`), determine what column the ball will land in after falling from its starting position. Each `/` moves it to the left by 1 column and each `\` moves it to the right by 1 column.

#### Sample input

```
    .
  /   \  \
    /   /
 \   \/  \
   \   /\
    \ /\  \
     \    /
```

#### Sample output

The ball starts in column 5, hits the `/` on line 3, then the three `\`'s on lines 5 through 7 for a final position of:

```
7
```

Note that columns are 1-indexed, mostly for consistency with text editor conventions.

#### Edge cases

If the ball hits a `/` in the first column, it's eternally stuck in the nonexistent column 0. Your program should handle this correctly by printing `0`.

If the ball hits either side of a `\/` pattern, the result is undefined. Your program is permitted to terminate with no output, loop infinitely, or print an error message (my solution prints `-1`), but it must not print anything that can be perceived to be valid output.

If the ball hits the left slash in a `\\` pattern, it should end up directly beneath the right slash, not to the right of it. The solution I originally envisioned was prone to getting this wrong, so don't go down that path!

There may or may not be spaces after the `.` or the last `/` or `\` on each line. Your program should not rely on such padding being available. On a similar note, there may or may not be any lines following the first line.

You may assume that the first line will have zero or more spaces and exactly one `.`. Subsequent lines, if any, will have zero or more spaces and zero or more slashes.

#### Implementation details

Your program may read from a file (specified as a command-line argument) or read from standard input, at your convenience.

Your program must output a single number to standard output. (Yes, a trailing newline is fine. Yes, the number may have more than one digit.)

#### Test cases

> Input:
>
> ```
> .
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 1
> ```
>
> Note that the input here is exactly one byte. This is the smallest case you should be able to handle.

> Input:
>
> ```
>  .
>  \
>   \
>    \
>     \
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
>  6
> ```
>
> Note that there are no spaces after these slashes.

> Input:
>
> ```
>   .
>   /
>  /\\  /  \
> //\ \/// //
> \\/ \/\ /\/
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 0
> ```

> Input:
>
> ```
>   .
> / / /
>  \\\
>   /\\
>  /   \
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 1
> ```

> Input:
>
> ```
>    .
>
>
>  \
>        /
> /
>
>       \
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 4
> ```

> Input:
>
> ```
>  .
>  \
>
> \/\/\/
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> (anything but a nonnegative number)
> ```

#### Closing remarks

This question is similar to [Simulate a (gravity-based) billiard-ball-type computer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/simulate-a-gravity-based-billiard-ball-type-computer), but significantly simpler, so hopefully it will gain more interest.

I have a 169-character solution in Python. I'm sure the talented golfers here can tear that record to pieces, though. :^)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in characters will be accepted at the end of the month!

Comment: It's also very similar to [A Mere Bagatelle](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3593/a-mere-bagatelle) with a slightly different import format and only one throw. You can borrow and modify my test scripts if you want.

Comment: Well, shoot, the title of that question wasn't suspicious enough for me to check it. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's okay, that question was two and a half years ago.

Comment: I suggest that in the last example, the output should be "The ball is stuck".

Comment: Does it count as the end of the month yet >.<

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Python, 143B

```
import sys
for l in sys.stdin:
 a=l.find('.')
 if a>-1:F=a
 elif F>-1: 
    if'\\/'in l[F-1:F+2]:z
    F+={'\\':1,'/':-1}.get((l+' '*F)[F],0)
print F+1
```

Using the space/tab indentation trick. I haven't done anything particularly clever here. `F` is the current index, `l` is the current line; `z` is undefined so it throws an exception, which is definitely not a positive integer, handling the `\/` situation.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 37 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
¶¡ð«ć'.ksvU…/ \yXD>‚èJD„\/Qiõqëнk<X+]>
```

Input as a multi-line string. Outputs `\/` if the ball is stuck.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0LZDCw9vOLT6SLu6XnZxWeijhmX6CjGVES52jxpmHV7h5fKoYV6MfmBm4eHVF/Zm20Rox9r9/6@kpKSgx6UQw8UVow@CQD4A) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9W@f/QtkMLD284tPpIu7pednFZ6KOGZfoKMZURLnaPGmYdXuHl8qhhXox@YKZO4eHVF/Zm20Ro19ba/df5H62kp6SjoKSgF5OnEBMDJKAkjALSYHmwAgV9IKEPlIkBMiFK9IFcIENfX18ByMwDyemD@EBRINaH6wVKg3XHQADYLAhDH8kSkEoQhNuuALZTHyymgOQcmHNBNupDkFIsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
¶¡                       # Split the (implicit) input-string on newlines
                         # (work-around instead of `|`, because it will stop at empty lines)
  ð«                     # Add a trailing space to each line (work-around because indexing
                         # -1 in 05AB1E will wrap around to the other side)
    ć                    # Extract head; pop and push the remainder-lines and first line
                         # separated to the stack
     '.k                '# Get the 0-based index of "." in this first line
s                        # Swap to get the remainder-list of lines
v                        # Loop over each line `y`:
 U                       #  Pop and store the top value (the index) in variable `X`
       X                 #  Push the current index `X`
        D>               #  Duplicate it, and increase the copy by 1
          ‚              #  Pair to [X, X+1]
      y    è             #  Index both of those into the current line `y`
            JD           #  Join the two characters together, and duplicate it
              „\/Qi      #  If it's equal to "\/":
                   q     #   Stop the program
                         #   (after which the string is output implicitly as result)
                  ë      #  Else:
                   н     #   Only leave the first character (at index `X`)
  …/ \              k    #   Get its 0-based index in string "/ \"
                     <   #   Decrease it by 1
                      X+ #   And add it to `X`
]                        # After the loop:
 >                       # Increase the top of the stack (`X`) by 1
                         # (after which it's output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

### CJam, 61 bytes

```
qN/('.#)\_:,0+:e>f{' e]" /"f#0\+}{1$1$=\@2$-_@=@[\]$[W1]#/z}/
```

If the rule regarding `\/` is lifted (and we are not required to handle it), this can be shortened to **41** bytes:

```
qN/('.#)\_:,:e>f{' e]" /"f#0\+0+}{1$=-}/
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 11, <s>213</s> <s>208</s> <s>190</s> <s>175</s> <s>162</s> 160 bytes

```java
s->{int r=s.indexOf('.'),c;for(var x:s.split("\n"))if((c=(x+=" ".repeat(r+2)).charAt(r))!=46&&(r+=c<33?0:c<48?-1:x.charAt(r+1)==47?r/0:1)<0)return 0;return++r;}
```

Throws a division by zero error when we are stuck inside a `\/`.

-5 bytes thanks to *@EdgyNerd*
-17 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##fVLBctsgEL33K7Y6JDCqwW48bce26ukhxyaHHKseKMYNqYM0C/Iok/G3uwtIbprxRALm7fJ29y3woPZq8rD5c9Q75T18V9Y9vwOwLhjcKm3gJprJAZrdBbTuN3i@JOeBJg0fVLAabsBBBUc/@focuVh5Yd3G9Ldbdiku@Qe93DbI9gqhX3jh250NrKhdwbndMqYr1pdVAYVA0xoVGJYfORf6XuE3Mjh/X80/XVyQu9Krq6v1dKFX8y/ryWzRn0jljFfV/PMa5XQx46spRxM6dDBdZlCWuDwco/K2@7UjyYPyfWM38EiND@39@AmK566D8aQyIlE7AEmgruOMVrYlweijRZ52kkOONLLky7C8DbJIxzhWEf@bqWKOOCUd071iDuJoiSXrpCuSZaxKsqQEgi7uyWhnPfJMFiIODaXP5SYikGcLx5j4/2st6ZDJB2fFjm1FPTKP4vScXt5I4g8Pzrq2C@Od4FMGAHdPPphH0XRBtMQLO8ec0Cyzh7IH0Croe3bda9MG2zgwPX8jQXGN2CA0WneIZrOAoqSAIVeSeTj@BQ)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                             // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  int r=s.indexOf('.'),          //  Get the index of the dot on the first line
      c;                         //  Temp integer
  for(var x:s.split("\n"))       //  Split the input by newlines, and loop over the lines:
    if((c=(x+=" ".repeat(r+2))   //   Append trailing spaces to the line if necessary
          .charAt(r))            //   Get the character at the current index of this line
       !=46                      //   If this is NOT the first line (the char isn't a dot):
       &&(r+=c<33?               //    If the current char is a space:
              0                  //     Index `r` remains the same
             :c<48?              //    Else-if it's a '/':
              -1                 //     Index `r` is decreased by 1
             :x.charAt(r+1)==47? //    Else-if we're stuck in a `\/`:
              r/0                //     Divide by 0 to exit with an error
             :                   //    Else (it's a '\'):
              1)                 //     Index `r` is increased by 1
         <0)                     //    If `r` is now -1:
      return 0;                  //     Return 0
  return++r;}                    //  After the loop: return the index `r` + 1
```

Comment: I don't know Java at all, but wouldn't causing an error be shorter than returning -1?

Comment: @EdgyNerd Thanks, that indeed saves 5 bytes. :)

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks. And been able to save a few more bytes by getting rid of the brackets by putting everything inside the `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 124 bytes

```python
import sys
for l in sys.stdin:i=('.'in l)*l.find('.')or(i<0)*i-2*('\\/'in l[i-1:i+2])or' \\'.find((l+i*' ')[i])+i
print(i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYs9DoMwDEb3nMKb8yOSQjdET4LZEKqlNEEhC6dPE2gtS/Z7/ryf@R3DsxT@7DFlOM5DbDGBBw4N7JFXDiO/JFqsyivt7cZhbaxikjw9lOZu0BKJ3BWZuetHNsNS7whEeD9Ib1gjoJp5UYbFnjhkyaZXpUAtKwBcnVRbNNHAicZA7icbuPtMdflHLw/uCw)

Also works in Python 2.

#### Explanation

```python
for l in sys.stdin:i=          # Change value i for each line in the input
('.'in l)*l.find('.')          # Set i to (0-indexed) dot position if present
or(i<0)*i                      # Keep i fixed if it is below zero
-2*('\\/'in l[i-1:i+2])        # Set i to -2 if \/ trap is encountered
or' \\'.find((l+i*' ')[i])+i   # Else: move position based on character
print(i+1)                     # Print final 1-indexed position
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 95 bytes

```
[:>[:(<"1@|.@}.([:(1&{+_*0>[:*/2-/\])(]+{~ ::])^:(<3))&.>/@,2<@i.~{.)[:(0,'/ \'<:@i.]);._1 LF,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BbsIwDIbvfopfHEgDxW7ZtEPWokqTOHHaFZcepiGYhPYAHbx657RdhcbBThzl@/Plq5uxO6IMcEiRIVitGG/vu223D5t9SIpZXv1wdeXEhnzeLptFZucLWa9Ea5/Uy/aGEGp/sLtP3s95I1W6Lqoz31r2BmWpE6grgh3V/pWbHLttWnee6PPj9I0cJY5w7IguKBnXKBEyAhOU0NfQrP9BLz10MWQgRiQyEIKo2hoBEYWKCERI1URsFhUL6nOyfzlTjAExSDW@LLHLKHAn/cAZSDTKIpoIjfuJfJ7Ix8@S2d3JNcPV7hc)

Returns infinity `_` when the ball gets stuck.  Lost many bytes handling that special case.  Otherwise it's more or less a simple reduction of the rows.  Could surely be golfed further.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 123 bytes

```javascript
x=>(g=(i,c)=>y[j++][i]==c?g:y[j]+1?(k=y[j][i])=='/'?g(i-1,'\\'):k=='\\'?g(i+1,'/'):g(i,g):i)(x.indexOf`.`,j=0,y=x.split`
`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BboMwEETv/grfbAviTW4V0oZbrz30mEUCgUEmBCiQCr6erhsUWR6P345G2xa/xVxOflxO/VC5vcZ9xatuUPu4NHjdbm0UZTefIZZpk/A3iy6pvmNwjA2iApU22p8usSJSJrkzYhNYxAwYsY0bk3ijV@v7yq1fdW7zuMVzvOFq57HzSy5ys4vJ/Tz95LSqZ2Xs5Irq03fue@tLfY7Vc6k/GL/y1CP1uX0Uo@aVy6Gfh87Zbmh0rVdjzG4FCmmFJCH/70tYGQcuQUgg4jdAAJIEABJAEAF74ikcYcYhThQ6ICi8q3gsxFEuQyuIw9N7A8F1fP4A)

0-index, output `g` if stucked